# what methods of SampleBuffer do I must use for measurement of frame rate?

Tags: ios, camera, frame, cmsamplebuffer

I work with AvFoundation. I need to measure accurately frame rate from ios camera.

Algoritm:

**Frame rate** = `1/(time(f2)-time(f1))`  = __  (*frame per second*);

Where time(f2) – it's time when come second frame, and (f1) – it's time of first frame. 
How do it with using sampleBuffer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer)`

Something like this (in swift, a little awkward because I couldn't find a `CMTime` 1/x):

```
let delta = CMTimeSubtract(CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(buf2), CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(buf1))

// awkward 1/x, beware that delta.value may overflow as a timescale
// what's the right way?
let frameRate = CMTime(value: CMTimeValue(delta.timescale), timescale: CMTimeScale(delta.value))

// maybe you want floating point instead of CMTime:
let frameRateAsFloat64 = CMTimeGetSeconds(frameRate)
```